# Selection to join the tables VBFA and VBRK

Tags: abap, sap-erp

I have done a selection of the table `VBFA`, that has selected various SD documents based on the code below, and another selection of the table `VBRK` that has selected the documents that do not have a `NETWR = 0`. What I want to achieve is to select only those SD documents that are `NETWR NE 0`.
The code for the selection of the table `VBFA` is as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM vbfa AS v INTO TABLE gt_vbfa_inv
      FOR ALL ENTRIES IN gt_vbak
      WHERE vbelv = gt_vbak-vbeln
        AND vbtyp_n IN ('M', 'O', 'P', '5', '6')
        AND stufe = '00'
        AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM vbfa
                           WHERE vbelv = v~vbeln
                             AND posnv = v~posnn
                             AND vbtyp_n IN ('N', 'S')
                             AND stufe = '00' ) .
```

And the code for the selection of the `VBRK` table is as follows:

```
IF sy-subrc = 0.
      SELECT DISTINCT * FROM vbrk
        INTO TABLE gt_vbrk
        FOR ALL ENTRIES IN gt_vbfa_inv
        WHERE vbeln EQ gt_vbfa_inv-vbeln
          AND netwr NE 0.
  ENDIF.
```

Is there any way to merge these to two selection via a new Select or a Loop condition, that will select the documents of the table `VBFA`, where the documents will not have a `NETWR = 0` (or `NETWR NE 0`)?

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: is your aim a performance improvement or readability improvement? They are not equal and getting rid of the multiple selects is not a panacea. You may achieve more just by getting rid of SELECT * and/or by CDS views

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My standard approach for converting code using `FOR ALL ENTRIES` to a `JOIN` is this.

0. Convert it to the new SQL syntax with `@` in front of every variable.
1. Replace the `SELECT *` with the fields I actually need. This is important, because JOINs between two tables will always have duplicate field. So `SELECT *` doesn't work. And it's a bad practice anyway. You almost never need *all* the fields, so `SELECT *` is almost always a waste of memory and CPU cycles.
2. Take both SELECTs and prefix every column name with the table. For example `AND stufe = '00'` becomes `AND vbfa~stufe = '00'`
3. Take the FOR ALL ENTRIES from the second and turn it into a JOIN-condition on the first select. So

```
   FROM vbrk
     FOR ALL ENTRIES IN @gt_vbfa_inv
     WHERE vbrk~vbeln = @gt_vbfa_inv-vbeln
       AND vbrk~netwr <> 0.
```

becomes

```
   JOIN vbrk
     ON vbrk~vbeln = vbfa~vbeln AND 
        vbrk~netwr <> 0.
```

4. Use an inline data declaration for the result-set. That way you don't need to manually create a table- and structure type for holding the results. The end-result would thus look something like this (untested code):

```
    SELECT vbfa~somefield1
           vbfa~somefield2
           vbfa~somefield3
           vbrk~somefield1
           vbrk~somefield2
       FROM vbfa 
       JOIN vbrk ON
            vbrk~vbeln = vbfa~vbeln AND 
            vbrk~netwr NE 0.
       INTO TABLE @DATA(gt_results)
          FOR ALL ENTRIES IN @gt_vbak
          WHERE vbfa~vbelv = gt_vbak-vbeln
            AND vbfa~vbtyp_n IN ('M', 'O', 'P', '5', '6')
            AND vbfa~stufe = '00'
            AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM vbfa AS vbfa2
                               WHERE vbfa2~vbelv = vbfa~vbeln
                                 AND vbfa2~posnv = vbfa~posnn
                                 AND vbfa2~vbtyp_n IN ('N', 'S')
                                 AND vbfa2~stufe = '00' ) .
```

By the way: If `gt_vbak` comes from a SELECT too, then you likely can integrate this as another join here, too.